# pycharm pykml import error

Tags: python, pycharm, lxml, kml, pykml

I am trying to run a pykml project on pycharm.
I have installed pykml and xlml packages using easy_install command on OS X.
However the lines

```
from lxml import etree
from pykml.parser import Schema
from pykml.factory import KML_ElementMaker as KML
from pykml.factory import GX_ElementMaker as GX
```

produce `"Unresolved reference" error.`
I am positive I successfully installed lxml and pykml.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you configured the correct interpreter path for the project and installed the dependencies into that path?

Comment: done it and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the correct interpreter path for the project and install the dependencies into that path.